# vim + ESLint: override the default .eslint file with a project-specific one

Tags: vim, eslint, vim-plugin

## My Settings

I am using [ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console) with vim. ESLint executable and options files (`.eslintrc.js`) are configured within `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:ale_javascript_eslint_executable="/usr/local/bin/eslint"
let g:ale_javascript_eslint_options="-c /Users/adam/team-standard/.eslintrc.js"

...

let g:ale_linters = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
\   'javascript': ['eslint'],
\}
```

The `team-default/.eslintrc.js` is our team's standard coding style, based on a [eslint-config-airbnb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb). It is kept in a shared github repository.

## My Problem

Many GitHub projects have their own `.eslintrc.js` files. When I open a project with an `.eslintrc.js` file, I want the files within that project to be checked with the project's file, not with the default file.

In another words, I want vim to look for an `.eslintrc.js` file in the current file's directory hierarchy, take the one closest to the file, and revert to the default if none is found.

## What Have I Tried

- STFW
- Looked at public `.vimrc` files with `.eslintrc.js` at github ([example](https://github.com/lavie/vim/blob/master/.vimrc))

## My Question

How can I configure vim, [ale](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) and ESLint to look for an `.eslintrc.js` file up the current js file directory hierarchy, and revert to a predefined file if none is found?

Answer (score 0):

Following ["Is there a way to specify a default eslint configuration file when using ALE plugin of Vim?"](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16302/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-default-eslint-configuration-file-when-using-ale-plu)

The easy solution is placing the default configuration file at `~`, either directly or by sym-linking, and removing the `g:ale_javascript_eslint_options` line from the configuration.

This way, ESLint will use the first `.eslintrc.js` file it finds down the directory hierarchy.